# Why are there questions with duplicate tags once in a while?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, user-interface

The original question title had been *Why does the system allow adding duplicate or even multiple tags?*

<strike>Just look at this questions tags to see the issue.</strike> I've been unable to reproduce this now both during initial posting and while trying to retag with a duplicate one.

Consequently the remaining (minor) question is why there are still duplicate tags once in a while, like for example this [revision 2](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/949765/list).

Presumably this could be caused by related tags having been merged into one, i.e. the renaming/merging of a `tag-b` into semantically identical `tag-a` on a question featuring both former tags yields a duplicate `tag-a` afterwards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've added a moderator function which deduplicates all current question tags, and all post history tag entries.

So the next time there's a duplicate tag problem, just flag one of them for moderator attention and we'll run the tag deduplicator page.

Answer (score 5):

Typically, if you try to add a duplicate tag, when you save, the duplicate is removed. However, in this case it appears it was part of a global retagging by a 10k+ user, note the change comment "win32-api -> winapi (latter has greater participation)". It must be that when this is done, the same duplicate check is not run. I would wager though, that if someone editted the question after that and did not touch the tags, the duplicate would be removed.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - the latter is probably the way things are, though this would classify as an after the fact solution to a problem best solved at its origin from a theoretical point of view, see my comment on TheTXIs answer.

Comment: @Steffen, agreed it is as you say, likely a bug of low priority.

Comment: Just FYI, 10k+ rep users can't do this global retag business. That's a moderator action. But your explanation is probably correct.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes tags are merged and get overwritten to be something else. So if you have something like

"C#" and "C-Sharp" and C-Sharp is merged, you will end up with two instances of "C#" on the question.

Comment: That's what I've suspected already. Still this would classify as a bug, wouldn't it? Admittedly an extremely minor one, but the engine could and should take care of that - and I'm not even starting to challenge the referential integrity of the SO database schema here, which shouldn't allow for something like this to happen in the first place ;)